# Поисковый запрос в JIRA на Python3

Tags: html, python-3.x, jira

Доброго времени суток. Я в процессе обучения Python (кнопаю сразу Python3) и поставили передо мной такую задачу:
Написать скриптик на Python, работающий по принципу "ввёл JQL-запрос, получил список тикетов, вывел его на экран"

Я только в процессе изучения языка (и это мой первый язык), так что работа с HTML для меня лес тёмный.

Собственно на данный момент я разобрался, что:

```
import urllib.request

url = '/ссылка на поиск issue в JIRA/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)                                                    
reading_link = response.read()
```

Вот этот участок кода откроет мне указанную линку, прочтёт её. Но вот как сделать так, чтобы *JIRA* съела мой JQL-запрос для advanced-поиска и выдала мне результат по моему запросу?

Т.е. мне понятно, что нужно добавить `input`, который будет принимтаь этот самый запрос, в стиле:

```
jql_input = input('Enter a JQL request: ')
```

Но вот как мне эту переменную послать куда надо - для меня загадка.
Может, тут кто поможет?)

Comment: Шаг №1: выясните какой конкретно запрос нужно делать (GET, POST какие конкретно параметры)¶ Шаг №2: выполните запрос на Питоне. Что-нибудь вроде: `results = requests.get('.../rest/api/2/search', params={'jql': 'your query', ...}).json()`¶ Обычно самая сложная часть это authentication Здесь может быть проще клиенсткой библиотекой воспользоваться.

Comment: Учитывая, что мне нужно, чтобы JIRA приняла мой запрос, могу сделать вывод, что запрос должен быть POST (Это, скорее, вопрос. Я HTML знаком очень поверхностно). И GET для того, чтобы получить результирующую страницу со списком тикетов. Вывести на экран - это уже парсинг результирующей страницы (как я себе это вижу).
Но:
1. Как узнать, какие конкретно параметры нужны? Где это можно вычитать, посмотреть?
2. О какой клиентской библиотеке речь?
3. Я правильно понял: лучше пользоваться не urllib, а импортировать 'requests'?
4. Просто для понимания ситуации: чем различаются urllib/urllib2/3 ?

Comment: Слова GET, POST это названия http методов, принимаемое и возвращаемое содержимое скорее всего в json формате, никакого отношения к html.¶ Учить сразу и http(rest) и Питон и jira тяжело наверно — постарайтесь на одной вещи за раз концентрироваться. Попробуйте jira rest api в гугл вбить, чтобы увидеть какие запросы ожидаются.¶ Клиентская библиотека на Питоне (если она существует) за вас http запросы делает. Вбейте в гугл: jira python client¶  requests рекомендуется разработчиками Питона.¶ Чтобы освоиться с http в Питоне, можно поставить httpbin сервер локально и тренироваться.

Comment: Да, в голове действительно каша и перепутались понятия html и http. Сейчас загуглил ‘python jira’, нашёл либу для змеи для работы с Jira api. Вроде, похоже на «оно». Буду теперь курить документацию по либе. Спасибо большое, что дали направление, куда копать)